# Spark on EC2: how to read LZO compressed parquet file

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, parquet, lzo

I would like to read a parquet file compressed with lzo algorithm. Let's suppose to run a spark-shell (in a spark cluster ec2-based, build with the ec2-script) and put this code in it:

```
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "myaccesskey")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "mysecretaccesskey")

val parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("s3://path/to/my/parquet/lzo/file")
parquetFile.first()
```

I receive this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
```

I have followed also this [guide](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2394) but the error remains the same. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the hadoop-lzo jar is on the classpath on executors?

Comment: I'm testing lzo in local mode for now, so the spark shell is launched as follow: spark-shell --master local[*] --jars /path/to/hadoop-lzo.jar